# Как найти координату точки, лежащей на перпендикуляре к линии?

Tags: математика, геометрия, координаты

Предположим, что есть некая прямая линия на координатной плоскости.
К этой линии проведен перпендикуляр в известном направлении длиной 10 единиц (константа).
Известны координаты начальной и конечной точек линии, а также координаты точки на линии, из которой проведен перпендикуляр (переменные).

С помощью каких геометрических формул можно найти координату второй точки перпендикуляра?

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предпочтителен пример решения на Python или псевдокоде.

Comment: Так Вам нужно решение или направление, куда копать? Если решение, то Вы ошиблись сайтом. А если направление, то почитайте про уравнение прямой и уравнение перпендикуляра к прямой, там не сложно.

Comment: берёте вектор `(x,y)` делаете ему перпендикуляр `(y,-x)` и потом его нормализируйте до нужной длины `x^2+y^2==100` `x = 70 - 30 ; y = 20 - 40` ...

Comment: Решать-то тривиально, просто очень много писать надо... Только решений будет два, потому что точно такая же точка имеется и с другой стороны.

Comment: Если не пугает... :) — https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B%28x+-+x1%29%5E2+%2B+%28y+-+y1%29%5E2+%3D%3D+L%5E2+%2B+%28x3+-+x1%29%5E2+%2B+%28y3+-+y1%29%5E2+%26%26+++%28x+-+x2%29%5E2+%2B+%28y+-+y2%29%5E2+%3D%3D+L%5E2+%2B+%28x3+-+x2%29%5E2+%2B+%28y3+-+y2%29%5E2+%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%7D%5D

Comment: @SagRU Вам понятно то, что написал  AlexGlebe?

Comment: @Harry там кстати есть уточнение про *"проведен перпендикуляр в известном направлении"*, так что решение всё же одно.

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Итоговый алгоритм получился такой (воспользовался подсказкой из [этого комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1442645/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8?noredirect=1#comment2574795_1442645)):

1. Нашел вектор CB: (9 - 6, 2 - 5) = (3, -3)
2. Нашел перпендикулярный ему вектор той же длины, повернув вектор CB на 90 градусов по часовой стрелке** (поменял местами `x` и `y` и заменил знак у нового значения `y`): (-3, -3)
3. Нормализовал вектор-перпендикуляр, разделив каждую из координат на длину линии: (-3 / 4.242, -3 / 4.242) = (-0.707, -0.707)
4. Умножил координаты нормализованного вектора на нужную длину перпендикуляра (2.828): (-0.707 * 2.828, -0.707 * 2.828) = (-1.999, -1.999)
5. Прибавил полученные координаты к координатам точки C и получил координаты нужной точки D: (6 + -1.999, 5 + -1.999) = (~4, ~3)

** Если нужно повернуть перпендикулярный вектор против часовой стрелки, то тогда необходимо поменять местами `x` и `y` и заменил знак у нового значения `x`

Полученные координаты (~4, ~3) совпадают с визуальным расположением точки на координатной плоскости.

Благодарю комментаторов за помощь!

Comment: осталось ещё второй результат добавить *их два : `(y,-x)` и `(-y,x)`* И второй результат : `(6+2,5+2)`

Comment: Вы не учли часть своего условия - *"проведен перпендикуляр в известном направлении"*, а не просто поворот на 90 градусов.